# web based diagramming tool with javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a web diagramming(visio) tool in javascript. im new to javascript but have extensive programming experience. i would like to get some feedback on what i need and what's the best way to go about writing this. thank you

Answer (score 9):

There's already [MxGraph](http://www.mxgraph.com/), which is free for non-commercial use. It should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on [Raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com)

[example](http://raphaeljs.com/ichart.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the latest javascript libaries eg: jQuery (www.jQuery.com) and the plugins. This will speed things up if you want to stick to JavaScript.

In my opinion though, with this type of project where a much richer user interface is required, it may be better to use flash or silverlight.

Comment: ...sounds like an interesting project, just found this example of one: flowchart.com/demo

Answer (score 1):

This one only does sequence diagrams, but I love it...

[websequencediagrams.com](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I started to write one in order to learn how to program using Prototype. I ended up with [this](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/jameslab/ajaxio/), but abandoned it. You're welcome to steal my code.

You can make boxes, label them, connect them and move then around on the screen. The connectors will follow.

It was all fun-and-games until I realized making a decent connector-routing algorithm was going to take over my brain....and that I had real "job-work" to focus on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is tool to help you. It's Javascript based and you can use the codes. Please check it out : [Javascript Diagram Builder](http://www.lutanho.net/diagram/)

Comment: the diagrams need to be editable, not just viewing